# How to list objects and (virtual directorys) using the REST API for OpenStack Object Store(Swift)

Tags: rest, openstack, openstack-swift

we use the REST API for OpenStack Object Store(Swift).
guessing the following structure does exist in the OpenStack Object Store:

```
/containername/object1.txt
/containername/object2.txt
/containername/pseudo-directoryname/object3.txt
/containername/pseudo-directoryname/object4.txt
```

To get a list of objects from a container we can use a HTTP GET request with the specified URL.
So far so good. Result:

```
/object1
/object2.txt
/pseudo-directoryname/object3
/pseudo-directoryname/object4.txt
```

The GET request combined with a delimiter parameter ("URL+ABSOLUTEPATH?delimiter=/") cuts the pseudo directories from the result.

```
/object1.txt
/object2.txt
```

I would like to have a list of all objects within the container combined with the pseudo directories within the container.

Is there a solution to get the following result without getting all objects and parse them on client side?

```
 /object1.txt
 /object2.txt
 /pseudo-directoryname/
```

I didn't find anything about wildcards when using the delimiter parameter. 
Something like "URL+ABSOLUTEPATH?delimiter=/*/".

Answer (score 1):

I was just trying to work the same thing out. Found the answer in the docs: http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/cli_swift_pseudo_hierarchical_folders_directories.html#list-pseudo-hierarchical-folders-request-http

Using their example (note the `prefix` and `delimiter` query string parameters):

```
$ curl -X GET -i -H "X-Auth-Token: $token" $publicurl/v1/AccountString/backups?prefix=photos/&delimiter=/
```

Would return:

```
photos/animals/
photos/me.jpg
photos/plants/
```